# How many documents can be retrieved from CouchDB in a single call

Tags: couchdb

There are 500,000 documents stored in a CouchDB database.  Client app needs to retrieve all docs for processing into another system.  Is there a recommended way for retrieving all?  I understand there is paging support using "limit" and "skip" parameters.  It looks like a call can be made to get total docs then use a loop to call CouchDB dynamically updating "limit" and "skip" values.  Is there an alternative way for retrieving all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from replication I think not.  Of course it really depends on specifics not given in the OP.  500k of 200b docs *may not* be a bandwidth issue but 500k of 100kb documents *might* be a consideration.

There a lot of ways to approach this and since there are a lot of details not given, all most can do is offer a generic approach which I will do here.

The essence is to use [/{db}/_all_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-all-docs) with a combination of `start_key`, `limit` and `skip`.

The initial state should be

- `start_key = null` Because null is first in the CouchDB [Views Collation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html#collation-specification)
- `limit = ?` Arbitrary as it depends on average document size, bandwidth, processing power etc.
- `skip = 0` One doesn't want to skip anything at the start

The general solution is to adjust `start_key` and `limit` according to the last response.

Do note that `skip` can [be very inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238261/how-to-use-the-skip-parameter-in-cloudant-or-couchdb). In this solution `skip` is either 0 or 1 which is quite OK.

Each successive state depends upon the prior response:

- `start_key = last rows doc key` Can't know what the next key is, right?
- `skip = 1` So the response doesn't include the last response doc

In other words, a subsequent request is saying "Give me the next set of docs starting one past the last document key received".

Here's a [nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano) based script that provides a skeleton upon which to throw meat.  It is naïve as it suggests URL credentials and has no error handling for clarity.

```js
const nano = require("nano")("http://{uid:pwd@address:port");
const db = nano.db.use("{your db name}");
const echo = (json) => console.log(JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2));
const processRows = (rows) => {  
    echo(rows);
};
(async () => {
    let start_key = null;
    let limit = 2; // whatever
    let skip = 0;
  let response;
    let more = false;
    
    do {
        if (response) {
            // next query is based on the last query.
            start_key = response.rows.pop().key;
            skip = 1;
        }
        response = await db.list({ start_key, limit, skip });
        processRows(response.rows);
        more = response.rows.length === limit;
    } while (more);
    console.info("Procesing completed.");
})();
```

Final words, this will return [_design_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/index.html#design-documents) too - probably want to filter those away.

**Update**
I neglected to add the actual answer: The default is to return *all* rows as stated in CouchDB document section [1.5.4.4. Using Limits and Skipping Rows](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#using-limits-and-skipping-rows), so it's up to the caller.